# Moq is making method call and returning real data, and not the return data in Setup

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I am trying to return a statically declared array of NWatchNativeNode[], but Moq seems to actually be calling the real method that goes to the gets the real system data.  Is the Setup in the below incorrect?

I want to make sure that when

`GetNodesInCriticalCondition()`  is called, `criticalNodes1` is returned.

**Unit Test Code**

```
var criticalNodes1 = new NWatchNativeNode[]
{
    factory.CreateNativeNode(NWatchNodeType.NetworkSwitch,
        "MySwitch",
        "MyAlias",
        12345
        ),
    factory.CreateNativeNode(NWatchNodeType.NetworkSwitch,
        "MySwitch2",
        "MyAlias2",
        54321
        ),
};

var mock = new Mock<NWatchCasModelStatusScheduleEntry>(_application);
mock.Setup(x => x.GetNodesInCriticalCondition()).Returns(criticalNodes1);

var nodes = mock.Object.GetNodesInCriticalCondition();
Assert.AreEqual(2, nodes.Length);  // This should return true
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `GetNodesInCriticalCondition` in your test. The mock is supposed to be passed to the subject under test that has a dependency on the mock. What you are essentially doing in that code is attempting to test Moq, which isn't really that useful.

Comment: Can you please give an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason that the `Mock` returns the real system data is that your method `GetNodesInCriticalCondition()` is not declared `virtual`.

In order for `Moq` to be able to setup the method calls, these methods have to be `virtual`, otherwise it cannot overwrite them and hence cannot intercept them, which results in the original method being called.

**Edit:**
If your method is `internal`, you have to give access to it to your *Unit Test project* and to *Moq*.
You can do this by adding
`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]` and
`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestProjectNameSpace")]`
to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file of the project you are creating mocks for.

Comment: One thing to also add onto your answer, because I am sure it will help someone in the future, is that my method was "internal", so that my Unit Test project had access to it, via `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestProjectNameSpace")`], but I also had to give InternalsVisible to Moq, by adding `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]` in the AssemblyInfo.cs file of the project I was trying to create mocks for.

Answer (score 0):

As per your request, here is a quick example of how to test with Moq.

Let us make some classes and interfaces to test to start with.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IEnumerable<int> GetFoos();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GetFoos()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly IFoo foo;

    public Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> SquareFoos()
    {
        foreach(var item in foo.GetFoos())
        {
            yield return item * item;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, `Bar` has a dependency on the `IFoo` interface. Now we want to test the functionality of `SquareFoos` on the `Bar` class. This is our subject under test. What we want to mock is the `IFoo` interface passed to the constructor of `Bar`. This gives us the following unit test setup.

```
// Arrange
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(m => m.GetFoos()).Returns(Enumerable.Range(1, 2));

var sut = new Bar(mock.Object);

// Act
var results = sut.SquareFoos().ToList();

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(2, results.Count);
```

In this case we mock out what `GetFoos` returns to allow us to test our `Bar` class.

Comment: This is good, and it makes sense, however, this is not what I am going after.  I have a concrete class, which you can consider a specialized "job".  For that very reason, this specialized "job" does not implement an interface.

Now, this job typically makes some REST calls to get nodes in critical condition, and then continues to do other things.  I simply want, instead of the REST calls, to provide some dummy static data, so that I can fully test the job.

Comment: Assuming that `GetNodesInCriticalCondition()` makes the REST call, what consumes that data? That is what you should be testing.

Comment: This same class actually has a runn "Run" method.  The first thing it does is call the `GetNodesInCriticalCondition()`.  It then goes into other methods that handle addding/removing from a collection, and kicking off some actions such as alerting, etc.

I was getting unexpected results from `mock.Object.Run()`, (when it was calling `GetNodesInCriticalCondition()`, it returned "real" data), and that's why my question was around this.  I actually fixed it, just now, by adding `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]` since `GetNodesInCriticalCondition()` is internal.